# How to Identify People in Text | NLP | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I'm looking to leverage NLP python packages to identify people's names in a string of text.

```
mystring = 'Elon R. Musk (245)436-7956 elonmusk@teslabooya.com Jeff Bezos (235)231-3432 jeffreyallenbiz@amizbiz.net Tim Apple apple.chickadee.org 432-455-5467'
```

Expected output would be a list of the names `['Elon R. Musk', Jeff Bezos', 'Tim Apple']`

Unsure if regex or NLP would be best for this.  This is just an example, but I'd like to apply the solution to more text in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a popular task called Named Entity Recognition (NER), and there are a lot of models available online to do this.

Here is a tutorial on how to do this with the well adopted library spacy.io
[https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/nlp-application-named-entity-recognition-ner-in-python-with-spacy/#:~:text=Spacy%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,very%20easily%20for%20NER%20tasks](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/nlp-application-named-entity-recognition-ner-in-python-with-spacy/#:%7E:text=Spacy%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,very%20easily%20for%20NER%20tasks).